# python add object to variable when using deepcopy

Tags: python

I've got a few questions. Keep in mind i need to use deep copy as my classes will be expanding in complexity.

- Is there a way to make it not reach the recursion limit when i do a deep copy?
- When I preform a deep copy I want the new copy to be appended to the NODES variable just like it does in the **init**?

---

```
import copy

# Global
NODES = []

# Classes
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Truck(Node):
    def __init__(self, name="", age=0):
        super(Truck, self).__init__(name=name, age=age)
        NODES.append(self)

class Car(Node):
    def __init__(self, name="", age=0):
        super(Car, self).__init__(name=name, age=age)
        NODES.append(self)

    def __deepcopy__(self, memo):
        print '__deepcopy__(%s)' % str(memo)
        return Car(copy.deepcopy(self, memo))


Truck( name="Tonka Truck")
Truck( name="Monster Truck")
Truck( name="Pickup Truck")
car = Car( name="Oldsmobile Car")
car.age = 55
new_car = copy.deepcopy( car )

type_name = "Car"
cars = [x for x in NODES if type(x).__name__ == type_name]
print cars

print "NODES:"
for node in NODES:
    print "\t", node.name, node.age
```

Comment: Sounds like a case for metaclasses. Good luck, they confused the hell out of me.

Comment: Why can't you do the first part of this in `Node.__init__`? You have all the relevant information by that point.

Comment: how would i do part 2 then?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 2):

First, you really should use a `defaultdict` for Toys. It just meet this requirement *If the superclass doesn't exists, it adds and appends the object*. So let's go with

```
Toys = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

If you did not want to use `copy.deepcopy`, you could simply change `Node.__init__` method to:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, superclass):
        self.name = name
        self.superclass = superclass
        Toys[superclass].append(self)
```

It works fine when you create a new Truck:

```
t = truck()
Toys['Trucks'][-1] is t
```

gives True

Unfortunately, `deepcopy` uses a special construction scheme and bypasses `__init__` here.

But when `__init__` can't do, just call `__new__` to help...

`__new__` is a lower level special method called as a class method to create the object before `__init__` is called. And even `deepcopy` created objects are created with `__new__`. As it is a class method, you just need to declare the *superclass* names (BTW a superclass is another animal and you **really** should use a different name...) as a class attribute.

You code becomes:

```
import copy
import collections

# Globals
Toys = collections.defaultdict(list)

class Node(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        obj = super(Node, cls).__new__(cls)
        superclass = cls.superclass
        Toys[superclass].append(obj)
        return obj

    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name

class Truck(Node):
    superclass = "Trucks"

class Car(Node):
    superclass = "Boats"

class Boat(Node):
    superclass = "Nodes"

class Plane(Node):
    superclass = "Planes"


t = Truck()
t.name = "Tonka Truck"
print Toys
t2 = copy.deepcopy( t )
print t, t2, Toys
```

With this output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Trucks': [<__main__.Truck object at 0x0000000002D71A20>]})
<__main__.Truck object at 0x0000000002D71A20> <__main__.Truck object at 0x0000000002D71B70> defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Trucks': [<__main__.Truck object at 0x0000000002D71A20>, <__main__.Truck object at 0x0000000002D71B70>]})
```

That proves that:

- `Trucks` list has automatically been added to `Toys`
- `t` created as `Truck()` as been correctly added to `Toys['Trucks']`
- `t2` create with `deepcopy` as been correctly added to `Toys['Trucks']`

You now just have to change to `superclass` name for this code to be acceptable...

Comment: just to be clear, you are saying i should not use 'superclass' since that is already being used in python as something else?

Comment: why use collections.defaultdict(list) over just empty [] or {}

Comment: Lastly, if i want any time a new node is created for it to get a new GUI where would i place that? `import uuid nodeID = uuid.uuid4()`